# Which is the the best fingeprint-reader program available?

Tags: software-recommendation, fingerprint-reader

Being new to Ubuntu and curious, I installed FingerPrint GUI from the web some days back, but it turned out to be a mess with too many password puzzles.

E.g., when I switch on my laptop, the DEFAULT login screen would ask for password, but at the same time the fingerprint reading window would also pop up from nowhere, making it difficult to enter the login password at the same time fingerprint detecting program would declare that because no finger was scanned 'AUTHENTICATION FAILED'. Later I had to re-install Ubuntu itself to start thing new.

I found Finger Print GUI to be a shabby one to be re installed.
So is there any other Finger scanning program for Ubuntu 12.10?

Comment: @Vitor Can you help here please?

Answer (score 1):

## **Fingerprint-GUI**

It is a Fingerprint Reader Application with GUI.

Have to get from [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/%7Efingerprint/+archive/fingerprint-gui).

[image]

For Install :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fingerprint/fingerprint-gui

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install libbsapi policykit-1-fingerprint-gui fingerprint-gui
```

Answer (score 0):

## [**Fprint**](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/fprintd/)

It is the Fingerprint Reader GUI application in Official Ubuntu [Repository](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=fprint&searchon=names&suite=saucy&section=all)

It also provide drivers for Fingerprint Readers.

Can be installed with:

```
sudo apt-get install fprintd fprint-demo libpam-fprintd libfprint0
```

[image]